# How do I place text fields correctly within an animated UIView?

Tags: xcode, animation, uiview, swift3, uitextfield

I am having problems with animating an UIView.
Everything is actually pretty basic: 
[My storyboard, because it easier to show a pic than to explain everything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp0s2.png)

As you can see, there is a white UIView in the middle ( behind the gray label that says "Navi ein" ). It has to TextFields and one button in the right bottom corner.

I now added an animation to this UIView, so when the user clicks the button "Navi" (placed in the navi.-bar, top left), the UIView flys in from the top to the center (centerY-constraint and alpha animation, very simple).

The animation works for the UIView, but the TextFields and the button are not shown after it. My question is: why? I would really appreciate your help! :-)

Please let me know if you need some code extracts, but it shoudn't be necessary.

EDIT: I now found the text fields and the button in my View Debugger, I just forgot to uncheck "Only show displayed views". But how to figure out what makes them disappear (or not even appear) when the app launches?

[View Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGBLy.png)

Comment: Have you tried Xcode's View Debugging feature to see where the missing views might be located or whether something is hiding them?  (It has a button that allows you to see clipped views.)

Comment: I'll try this out, thanks so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry! I just saw that I set all three items to hidden in my code. 
I've never thought about that so far, I just looked in my storyboard.
So the problem is solved, I just deleted the lines "streetTextField.isHidden = true" and so on.

Nevertheless, I think it is good to hear and to see that some problems that seem to be hard are very easy to solve.